# make and receive call betwen browser and phone to discuss like a simple call

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

```
<?php
// Include the bundled autoload from the Twilio PHP Helper Library
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$auth_token = '8XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
// In production, these should be environment variables. E.g.:
// $auth_token = $_ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
// A Twilio number you own with Voice capabilities
$twilio_number = "+12244073476";
// Where to make a voice call (your cell phone?)
$to_number = '+22678733599';
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
try {
    $client->account->calls->create(
        $to_number,
        $twilio_number,
        array(
            // two url can't function because the first url will be erase by the value of the second
            "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
        )
    );
    // echo "Started call : " . $client->sid;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error : " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

When I start the call to the phone number from twilio number, it's okay. But it is impossible to make communication.
How can I make communication after answering the call?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to record the user input, voice input?

Comment: is the voice input will permit to make discussion between the two number (twilio and phone number)?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your title says you want to connect a browser to a phone. However, your code only shows use of the REST API.

To create calls from a browser to a phone you need to use the [Twilio Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript). I would recommend that you go through the instructions to run the [Voice SDK quick start application](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-php). That will explain how making a call from a browser to a phone works and give you an example application to run and investigate. The quick start application is fully documented.

Comment: please! i downloaded Voice SDK quick start application, but it's don't help me really. In fact, i can't found the artisan file to run the application, when i do "php artisan serve".

Comment: Make sure you read the instructions for running the application locally: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-php#local-development. The instructions do not mention using `php artisan serve` but `make serve` instead. All the instructions are in the README.

Comment: excuse me, is different make serve and php artisan serve ? i use laravel 5 and i also new in this. Thanks

Comment: In this case, the difference is that the instructions for running the application tell you all the commands you need to run. Follow the instructions and you should be fine.

Comment: excuse me, i try following the instructions but i meet this error "make : command not found" when i run make serve

Comment: Sounds like you need to install make then.

Comment: how to install it, please?

Comment: I don’t know what system you’re running, you would probably find some pretty good instructions by searching for how to install make on your operating system.

Comment: okay, i will search to see. My system is window.

Comment: I bet you can find out how to do it, then follow the instructions here and you’ll be away!